# Why is form data not being sent to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am implementing a chat, creating a registration window, and it is necessary that the data from the form be sent to the server, so that it is then sent to the client side to be displayed in the list of clients. But for some reason the data from the form does not come, what's the problem? Here is the form index.html:

```html
<form class = "FORM" action="/" method="post">
  <label>Username</label><br>
  <input type = "TEXT" class = "CHECK" autocomplete="off" name="Username">
  <button type = "submit" class="BTN" onclick="redirect()">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is the server on express index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require('./database/database'); // подключаемся к бд
const urlencodedParser = express.urlencoded({extended: false});
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const {Server} = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server);

const port = 3000;
let id = 0;
let users = {};

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', (request, response ) => {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    app.post("/", urlencodedParser, function (request, response) {
        if(!request.body) return response.sendStatus(400);
        console.log(request.body);
        //response.send(`${request.body.userName} - ${request.body.userAge}`);
    });
.....
```

Why is the data not coming from the form to the server?

Comment: have you tried reformatting your html and remove those spaces? from "```<input type = "TEXT" class = "CHECK"```" to "```<input type="TEXT" class="CHECK"```" (for each html element)?

Comment: Why are you registering your `app.post()` handler _inside_ the socket connection handler? Move it out and I suspect this will all start working. Also, your `app.get("/")` is redundant since `express.static()` will already be serving your `index.html` file

Comment: @Kristian Spaces around the `=` are allowed.

Comment: What is the content of the `redirect` function? Does it preventDefault?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither moving past sockets nor removing spaces helped. The function redirect() redirects the user to another page when the button is clicked (and the form data itself is passed through localStorage, which seems wrong to me). const redirect = ()=> {
    window.location = 'client/chat.html'
}

Comment: So on clicking the submit button you navigate to another page instead of submitting the form and you're wondering why your form data doesn't submit?

Answer (score -1):

You would have to make an axios post request to the endpoint.

if you're using vanilla javascript, you also need to add eventlistener to the form.

```
const form = document.getElementsByClassName("FORM");
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const userName = event.target.Username.value;
if (!userName) alert("Username is required");
else {
    axios
        .post(
            "http://localhost:3000/", {
            userName
        })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);

        /*depending on what response you get from the server, 
you may want to use .map() method to display all the usernames*/
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    event.target.reset();
 }
})
```

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect. HTML forms are perfectly capable of submitting data without JavaScript